# Doesn't English have vowel harmony?

Tags: linguistics, vowels, language-formation, germanic-languages

Perhaps I'm not educated in this subject, but if vowel harmony means "***all the vowels in a word to be members of the same subclass***" then does this mean that English has vowel harmony too? For instance, words like *l**a**mb**a**ste, p**a**rk**a**, **a**lm**o**st, **a**ls**o**, d**o**ll**a**r/sch**o**l**a**r/c**o**l**ou**r (AUS/UK English), **ee**r**ie**, c**o**ll**a**ge/m**o**nt**a**ge, f**o**ll**o**w/sw**a**ll**o**w/h**o**ll**o**w, f**i**n**i**sh*, f**o**lkl**o**re, b**o**rr**o**w, m**o**r**o**n, **a**rd**o**r, **a**lth**ou**gh, d**i**m**i**n**i**sh, etc....use the same vowel class in their pronunciation or spelling. Isn't that a "vowel harmony", in a way? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, English doesn't have vowel harmony. Vowel harmony isn't some words happening to only have vowels of one class, but a requirement that **all** words **must** have vowels of only one class. Most commonly, this requirement is only strictly enforced in inflectional endings, while roots can sometimes break it; for instance, loanwords in Finnish often break vowel harmony (like _miljonääri_ ‘millionaire’, which has the back vowel o in an otherwise front-vowel-only word, etc.).

Comment: I know that English doesn't have vowel harmony (when it comes to inflections and suffixes), but aren't the words in the opening post an example of "vowel harmony"? I'm not that familiar with the term.

Comment: No, they're just an incidental case of words only containing front or back vowels. Vowel harmony refers to the requirement that all words in a language **must** only contain one class, not incidental cases where individual words do.

Comment: You may find it helpful to take a look at Turkish, which does have vowel harmony. Turkish has 'back' vowels and 'front' vowels and if the vowel of the first syllable of a word is a back vowel, so too are the vowels of subsequent syllables. And if the vowel of the first syllable is a front vowel, so too are the following ones. [link](http://www.turkishclass.com/turkish_lesson_59)

Comment: Interesting question, even if the answer is "No."

Comment: A subtle form of vowel harmony *might* exist, for example to explain why certain diphthongs (*au*) are allowed and others  (*ao*) are not. (It might be overly harsh to say that *ao* is not allowed; it simply doesn't appear to exist, or is at least extremely rare or restricted to loan words.)

Comment: The question in your title, "Doesn't English have ... ", is opposite to the question in the text: " ... does this mean that English has ... ". It's an unfortunate feature of English that questions posed in the negative generate confusion; so here, no-one is sure whether the answer "yes" to the title question means (logically) "yes, it doesn't" or "yes, it does", and similarly for the answer "no".

Comment: BillJ, I am aware of Turkish grammar. They have vowel harmony in like 95% of their words, and also in their suffixes (unlike in English and many other languages). You say: 

"if the vowel of the first syllable of a word is a back/front vowel, so too are the vowels of subsequent syllables."

Isn't that the case of the (English) words that I provided in my opening question? They apply to that case. But nobody has yet to say why or how come this has come to be - Why some English words "technically" have a vowel harmony. And what is that exactly called.

Comment: @E.Groeg: I'm not sure why you think it needs to be explained how "silky" came to have the vowels that it has. It just has the vowels of its constituent parts, "silk" and the suffix "-y". I don't know of any special name for this.

Comment: @sumelic, I believe they call this suffix "-y" a diminutive. You're right that it shouldn't be an example.

Answer (score 27):

English doesn't have vowel harmony.

"Vowel harmony" refers to situations where there is some **process** that changes vowels to be in the same class as other vowels in the word, and/or there is a **constraint** against having vowels of different classes in a word.

You can see examples of vowel harmony processes in Turkish on e.g. this web page: [Vowel Harmony](https://turkishteatime.com/turkish-grammar-guide/vowel-harmony/) (some examples: the plural of *kedi* is *kediler*, the plural of *kuş* is *kuşlar*).

Processes like this may be explained in terms of a "constraint"; vowel harmony constraints often also seem to show up separately in base vocabulary e.g. there are few native Finnish roots that contain both front and back vowels. In many (perhaps most? I don't know) languages with vowel harmony, this constraint is violable and "disharmonic" words with vowels from conflicting classes do exist. In particular, it seems compound words are rarely subject to vowel harmony constraints (they aren't in Finnish or in Turkish), and loanwords may not be subject to vowel harmony constraints. But there's a difference between having a violable constraint, and not having any apparent constraint at all.

This is just a general summary. I am not an expert, and even experts still have much to learn about the specifics of what vowel harmony is.
Here are some more detailed explanations and discussions:

- "[Vowel Harmony: Statistical Methods for Linguistic Analysis](https://www.swarthmore.edu/sites/default/files/assets/documents/linguistics/2012_Knowles.pdf)", Rebecca Knowles
- *[Formal and Cognitive Restrictions on Vowel Harmony](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=ArpunEcGw6oC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&ots=RHh1ZqownC&sig=PWV-u39sKxDHtX4e2PdcWBaZzRk#v=onepage&q&f=false),* Sara Finley (Google Books)
- *[Effects of contrast recoverability on the typology of harmony systems](http://faculty.arts.ubc.ca/gohansson/pdf/GH_ContrRecovHarm.pdf),* Gunnar Ólafur Hansson

English doesn't have any processes or constraints like this (as far as I know) so it does not have vowel harmony.

There aren't any English suffixes that use different vowels depending on the vowels in preceding syllables, and there aren't any general restrictions based on vowel class of which vowels can co-exist in an English word.

The suffix *-y* found in *messy* is pronounced the same in the words *foamy, woody, warty, hearty* which all have different vowels.

Answer (score 6):

The English language doesn't have [vowel harmony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_harmony).  If it did, pronunciations of many words would be different.

> You would still *bequeath*, but probably *botrothe* yourself rather than *betrothe*, and while a lioness would remain a lioness, a goddess would perhaps be a *goddoss*. ([Source](https://www.quora.com/What-would-English-look-like-if-it-had-vowel-harmony))

Comment: Why would a lioness remain a lioness?

Comment: ^Yeah, wouldn't it be "lionios"?

Answer (score 0):

We do have incidents of vowel harmony, although it is not so developed as to be a part of our actual formal grammar or phonology. I.e., there are no rules dictating it, but it does exist as a phenomenon.

One example that came up for me recently was when I did a reading for some people in Turkey of all places. :-) There was a sentence that ended, “…the importance that owning a vehicle plays at every stage of life.” Somebody there objected to my reading of “at” as “et”. Yet this is what most speakers of American English would do except when reading very slowly and distinctly for a non-native speaker.

On the other hand, if the word “at” came after a low back vowel like “row,” we’d pronounce it closer to “at.”

Contrast:

There’s a row at the back.
There’s a tree at the end of the street.

Most speakers will pronounce something closer to “tree it the end of the street.”

Because nobody does it deliberately, we rarely even think about it, but actually pronouncing “the tree *at*…” feels odd in exactly the same way as “Izmir’a” would feel in Turkish. (The correct form would be “İzmir’e” (“to Izmir”).